# JetBrains HTML Live Edit (remote debugging) doesn't work properly

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I run "Debug index.html". JetBrains Intellij IDEA 2016.3 successfully connects to JetBrains IDE Support 2.0.9 on top of Chrome 57.0

But when I add something in html page (say `<h1>test</h1>`) in the Intellij it remains unchanged in the chrome. When I press 'rerun debug' in IDE or 'refresh' in the browser changes applies. As far as I know it's not supposed to work like that.

What can I try to make HTML pages reloads automatically?

Comment: Please make sure you have Live Edit plugin installed and enabled.

I'd also suggest setting 'Update' in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit to 'Auto in (ms)' and enabling 'Restart if hotswap fails'

Comment: @lena This resolved the issue. Thank you very much for your suggestions!